# How to concat two columns of table django model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am implementing search in my project what I want is to concat to column in where clause to get results from table.

Here is what I am doing:

```
from django.db.models import Q

if 'search[value]' in request.POST and len(request.POST['search[value]']) >= 3:
    search_value = request.POST['search[value]'].strip()

    q.extend([
        Q(id__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        (Q(created_by__first_name=request.POST['search[value]']) & Q(created_for=None)) |
        Q(created_for__first_name=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        (Q(created_by__last_name=request.POST['search[value]']) & Q(created_for=None)) |
        Q(created_for__last_name=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        (Q(created_by__email__icontains=search_value) & Q(created_for=None)) |
        Q(created_for__email__icontains=search_value) |
        Q(ticket_category=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        Q(status__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        Q(issue_type__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        Q(title__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
        Q(assigned_to__first_name__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |

    ])
```

Now I want to add another OR condition like:

`CONCAT(' ', created_by__first_name, created_by__last_name) like '%'search_value'%`'

But when I add this condition to the queryset it becomes AND

```
where = ["CONCAT_WS(' ', profiles_userprofile.first_name, profiles_userprofile.last_name) like '"+request.POST['search[value]']+"' "]
            tickets = Ticket.objects.get_active(u, page_type).filter(*q).extra(where=where).exclude(*exq).order_by(*order_dash)[cur:cur_length]
```

How do I convert this into an OR condition?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to put more code information? What exactly is the variable 'q' and what is 'Q'?

Comment: This could be a nice question about extensibility of Django ORM system. A good answer has a potentiality to inspire a new Django package or howto blog or patch, if more people think a function of more columns could be generally useful on the left side of relationship.

@ThiagoRossener: A [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) is a tool to create a general boolean expressions in Django ORM. There are also F objects for a field in an expression, Lookup and Transform objects etc., but something smart must be added imo to solve the original question.

Comment: With that `where` clause, let's hope that [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) never does a search on your site.

Comment: @C14L Thanks for the comics. Hassan, be aware of `extra(where=...)` without `params=...` argument. (read a [security warning about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra)).

Answer (score 7):

Advanced filters can be solved by
[Q() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and
[Query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/) like Func(), Value() and F().
The only used trick is a
[Custom Lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-lookups/) "rhs_only" that uses the right-hand-side of the lookup and ignores the left side, because it is easier to use all concatenated fields directly on the right side. A memorable function `concat_like` encapsulates that all to be easily used in queries.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Lookup, Q, Value
from django.db.models.fields import Field

def concat_like(columns, pattern):
    """Lookup filter: CONCAT_WS(' ', column_0, column_1...) LIKE pattern"""
    lhs = '%s__rhs_only' % columns[0]
    expr = Func(*(F(x) for x in columns), template="CONCAT_WS(' ', %(expressions)s)")
    return Q(**{lhs: Like(expr, Value(pattern))})

class Like(Func):
    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        arg_sql, arg_params = zip(*[compiler.compile(x) for x in self.source_expressions])
        return ("%s LIKE '%s'" % tuple(arg_sql)), arg_params[0] + arg_params[1]

@Field.register_lookup
class RhsOnly(Lookup):
    """Skip the LHS and evaluate the boolean RHS only"""
    lookup_name = 'rhs_only'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        return self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
```

All boolean expression and related objects are supported by this code. All arguments are correctly escaped.

Example usage:

```
>>> qs = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(id=1) | concat_like(('first_name', 'surname'), 'searched'))
>>> str(qs.query)   # sql output simplified here
"SELECT .. WHERE id=1 OR (CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, surname) LIKE 'searched')"
```

Answer (score 5):

Relevant documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

  - See also... `Value()` and `F()`
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses

You can reference annotated fields from inside the filter method.  As such, you can filter against two concatenated fields and add it as another OR condition like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

# Because we added user_full_name as an annotation below,
# we can refer to it in the filters
q.extend([
    Q(id__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    (Q(created_by__first_name=request.POST['search[value]']) & Q(created_for=None)) |
    Q(created_for__first_name=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    (Q(created_by__last_name=request.POST['search[value]']) & Q(created_for=None)) |
    Q(created_for__last_name=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    (Q(created_by__email__icontains=search_value) & Q(created_for=None)) |
    Q(created_for__email__icontains=search_value) |
    Q(ticket_category=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    Q(status__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    Q(issue_type__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    Q(title__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    Q(assigned_to__first_name__icontains=request.POST['search[value]']) |
    Q(user_full_name__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])  # <------
])


# Add the annotation to your queryset
# I'm not actually sure what the related_name or field_name for your user
# profiles are, so I'm pretending that tickets have a profile foreignkey field
# to where the first_name and last_name fields are
user_full_name_expr = Func(Value(' '), F('profile__first_name'), F('profile__last_name'), function='CONCAT_WS')

# The next two lines can be combined as long as the annotation comes first.
tickets = Ticket.objects.annotate(user_full_name=user_full_name_expr)
tickets = tickets.get_active(u, page_type).filter(*q).exclude(*exq).order_by(*order_dash)[cur:cur_length]
```

---

For fun, here's a working example based on the User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

User.objects.create(username='john', first_name='John', last_name='Jingleheimer-Schmidt')
User.objects.create(username='mike', first_name='Michael', last_name='Finnigan')

foo = User.objects.annotate(full_name=Func(Value(' '), F('first_name'), F('last_name'), function='CONCAT_WS'))
print(foo.filter(full_name__icontains='john'))

# outputs: [<User: john>]
```

Comment: Your solution is nice and handy. My solution is a little more DRY and worth of effort only if a filter by function of more columns should be used many times or to demonstrate that even a complicated filter element can be injected by a Q object.

Comment: My solution just stuck me as the easy way, and maybe the way that feels the most Django-like to me.  I really like your solution though and am filing it away for when I need to wrestle with complicated and/or repetitive querysets myself.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is, for create search FullText. I recommend use (http://haystacksearch.org/)

See documentation of Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)